How to handle "fatal: bad object refs/heads/main 2"?
I executed this command on my perfectly working repository and today I see that my main branch has lost all of its logs and commits I had done.
❯ git log
fatal: your current branch 'main' does not have any commits yet

How to fix this and why is this message occuring (fatal: bad object refs/heads/main 2)?
My remote repo is fine so i tried to pull from it
❯ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 3), reused 6 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), 1.15 KiB | 393.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: bad object refs/heads/main 2
error: https://github.com/SamarthPyati/matrix_in_c did not send all necessary objects



I don't think this is reproducible. Did you create main 2 locally or remotely? How exactly?

Regardless of the root cause, the simplest recovery might be to create a new local clone and take it from there. However, if you have local history which you had not pushed, you will probably need to recover the existing clone.

Check if .git/refs/heads/main 2 exists. If it does, just remove it. If not, try git udpate-ref -d "refs/heads/main 2". This branch should not have been created in the first place as it's not a valid git ref.

What's the output from git --version?

git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
